# Determining Linear Dependence/Independence of vectors in R2x2?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following vectors and need to determine if they are linearly independent/dependent. I know that for linear independence, the coefficients multiplied by each vector must equal zero, however, I am confused as to how I solve for that in 2x2 matrices.

My guess is I do C1(A) + C2(B) + C3(C) = 0.

Then from there, I need to prove that C1,C2,C3 (scalar constants) = 0.

My problem is I am not sure about how I go about doing that.

---

A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1\\ 
0& 0
\end{pmatrix}

C=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are linearly independent for sure.  When you add your sum that you said, you get $$\begin{pmatrix} c_1 & c_2\\ c_3 & c_1 \end{pmatrix}$$  Then, the only way that this is $0$ is if $c_1 =c_2 = c_3 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If you set $a A + b B +c C = 0$, then computing the matrix gives
$a A + b B +c C = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & a\end{bmatrix}  = 0$.
It follows that we **must** have $a=b=c= 0$, hence $A,B,C$ are linearly independent.