# In each part, determine whether the matrices are linearly independent or dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to do this as there was no example on linear dependence for matrices specifically in the book..

I tried seeing if the example in this post would work [Determining Linear Dependence/Independence of vectors in R2x2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684482/determining-linear-dependence-independence-of-vectors-in-r2x2)

but I dont know how he added the elements up to get c1 c2 c3 and then c1 again... that part lost me.. if that is even the right method.. how do I solve this?

Comment: he did not added $c_1,c_2,c_3$ to get $c_1$.. He did $1\cdot c_1+0\cdot c_2+0\cdot c_3$ and got $c_1$ as first row first column element....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for such $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ that $\alpha \neq 0$ or $\beta \neq 0$ or $\gamma \neq 0$ and:

$\displaystyle \alpha\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

If it's possible to find such $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ matrices are linear dependent, if it's not possible are linear independent.

In this case first you look at first row and first column: it must be $\alpha=-\beta$, so:

$\displaystyle \alpha\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}-\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$\displaystyle \alpha\begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Now look at second row second column, you must have $\alpha=-\gamma$, but when $\alpha=-\gamma$ you have:

$\displaystyle \alpha\begin{bmatrix}0 & -3 \\ -3 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Since capital letters are usually used for matrices, replacing $A,B,C$ with $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ is a good idea here...

Comment: is there a way you can do it formulaic instead of by just inspection?

Comment: Yes, you can write system of 4 equations from $\displaystyle \alpha\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and try to solve it.

Comment: oh. when I do that, alpha beta and theta all = 0, so its linear independent. am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a matrix as a vector here(for example, 2x2 matrix as a 4 dimensional vector) and use the defenition of linear dependence for vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition**.$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$
Let $\\v_1,\ldots,\\v_n$ be elements of a vector space $V$.  The statement "$\\v_1,\ldots,\\v_n$ are linearly independent" means that the equation
$$\alpha_1\\v_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\\v_n=\\0\tag{$*$}$$
has a unique solution.

To apply this definition to the matrices you are given, we set up the equation
$$\alpha_1\pmatrix{1&0\cr1&2\cr}+\alpha_2\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&1\cr}
  +\alpha_3\pmatrix{0&1\cr2&1\cr}=\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&0\cr}\ ,$$
solve it and see whether or not there is a unique solution.  Now. . .

. . . **suggestion**: let's **not** use any short cuts.  Short cuts are great in saving work when you know what you are doing.  But if you don't understand the reason behind the short cuts, then when you try a different type of problem you will find that you are totally lost.  I suspect this is your situation: I am sure you can do linear independence problems in $\Bbb R^3$, but perhaps you don't know the reasons, which means that you have difficulty with matrix independence problems when, really, they are fundamentally the same.

So, the next step is to turn the above matrix equation into scalar equations:
$$\eqalign{
  \alpha_1+\phantom{1}\alpha_2\phantom{{}+0\alpha_3}&=0\cr
           2\alpha_2+\phantom{1}\alpha_3&=0\cr
  \alpha_1+2\alpha_2+2\alpha_3&=0\cr
  2\alpha_1+\phantom{1}\alpha_2+\phantom{1}\alpha_3&=0\ .\cr}$$
Now we solve these equations by the usual method: put them into matrix form and row-reduce.  I'll leave the working up to you: you should get something like
$$\pmatrix{1&1&0&|&0\cr 0&2&1&|&0\cr 1&2&2&|&0\cr 2&1&1&|&0\cr}
  \sim\cdots\sim
  \pmatrix{1&1&0&|&0\cr 0&2&1&|&0\cr 0&0&3&|&0\cr 0&0&0&|&0\cr}\ .\tag{$+$}$$
Now we can solve this system.  Actually we don't want to solve it, we only need to know whether it has a unique solution or infinitely many solutions.  The answer is that it has a unique solution (can you give a reason why, by looking at the echelon form?) and so by definition, the three given matrices are linearly independent.

See if you can do the second problem by the same method.  I would also strongly recommend that you take a problem in say $\Bbb R^3$ which you know how to solve, and set it out in full detail like my example.  If you understand the principles, then linear independence problems all become pretty much the same, no matter whether you are dealing with vectors, matrices, polynomials or other examples.

Comment: im not sure if this is what you mean but i got the matrix on the bottom right that you got as well and solved for a b and c to be 0,0 and 0, therefor making it linearly independent. is that what you meant?

Comment: That's right, but I think it's worth spending a bit of time making absolutely sure you understand the issues.  If you look at equation $(*)$, it is obvious that $\alpha_1=0$, $\alpha_2=0$, $\alpha_3=0$ is always **a possible solution**.  But the point is that in this case it is **the ONLY possible solution**.  This is what makes the matrices linearly independent.

Comment: how can you figure out if its the only possible solution or not?

Comment: By looking at the final echelon form.  If it contains a non-leading (non-pivot) column on the LHS, for example,$$\pmatrix{1&2&3&|&0\cr0&4&5&|&0\cr0&0&0&|&0\cr0&0&0&|&0\cr}\ ,$$then there will be many solutions.  If, as in your question, it does not contain any non-leading column, then there will be only one solution.

Comment: what precisely are you refering to when you say the final echelon form?

Comment: The second matrix in equation $({+})$.  If you did different working for the row-reduction you might get a slightly different echelon form, but it will give the same answer.

Comment: what exactly defines a non leading non pivot column?

Comment: A leading entry is the first non-zero entry, if any, in a row.  In the example from my previous comment, the $1$ and the $4$.  A leading column is one which contains a leading entry (columns $1,2$) and a non-leading column is one which doesn't (column $3$).